# Flurry full screen is not displaying

Tags: android, flurry

I have to add Flurry full screen ad in my application, but its not displaying any add.
Please find my code below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle); 

    setContentView(R.layout.admob_layout);
    FlurryAds.setAdListener(this);

    mBanner = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bannerframe);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, Constant.F_API_KEY);
    // fetch and prepare ad for this ad space. won’t render one yet
    FlurryAds.initializeAds(FlurryAdActivity.this);
    FlurryAds.fetchAd(FlurryAdActivity.this, Constant.F_FULL_AD, mBanner, FlurryAdSize.FULLSCREEN);
}

public void spaceDidReceiveAd(String adSpace) {
    // called when the ad has been prepared, ad can be displayed:
    FlurryAds.displayAd(FlurryAdActivity.this, adSpace, mBanner);
}
@Override  
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
```

I have added required activity in manifest file.

Comment: Have you tried this on an Android device? or just the emulator?

Comment: Yes I'm testing only in Android device!

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"